# ceph quincy 17.2.6. stderr: Might need DB size specification, please set Ceph bluestore-block-db-size config parameter

Tags: filesystem, lvm, ceph

I am trying to add a DB device. The physical device is an SSD, in which I created as many logical volumes as OSDs. All the LV’s are in a volume group.

It turns out that when I run "ceph-volume lvm new-db”, I get an error: “stderr: Might need DB size specification, please set Ceph bluestore-block-db-size config parameter” .

(I note that there seem to be a typo in the name "bluestore-block-db-size”, I think that should be: bluestore_block_db_size)

I tried to fix the stderr with "ceph config set osd.0 bluestore_block_db_size 270000000000" (I set it to 270 GB in order to make it a bit smaller than the LV for this, which has 280 GB)

Hereunder the ful output, and I also show that bluestore_block_db_size is properly set.

````
--> Making new volume at /dev/cephdb03/cephdb03osd0 for OSD: 0 (/var/lib/ceph/osd/ceph-0)
 stdout: inferring bluefs devices from bluestore path
 stderr: Might need DB size specification, please set Ceph bluestore-block-db-size config parameter
--> failed to attach new volume, error code:1
--> Undoing lv tag set
Failed to attach new volume: cephdb03/cephdb03osd0
root@nerffs03:/# ceph config show osd.0 | grep db
bluestore_block_db_size                          270000000000                                                                                                                                                                                                                 mon                         
leveldb_log                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   default                     
root@nerffs03:/# ceph config get osd.0 bluestore_block_db_size 
270000000000
root@nerffs03:/# ceph --version
ceph version 17.2.6 (d7ff0d10654d2280e08f1ab989c7cdf3064446a5) quincy (stable)```

I am ware that this issue has been reported in : https://tracker.ceph.com/issues/55260 , but it is not clear to me if in quincy 17.2.6. that is fixed.

any help would be much appreciated!!
````